# Unable to get result rows via mysqli despite query working in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have the following query:

```
  SET @runtot:=0; 
  SELECT q1.d, q1.c, (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c) AS rt 
  FROM
  (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`date_seen`, '%d %b %Y') AS d, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM  `table` WHERE  `username` = 'myname' GROUP BY d
    ORDER  BY d) AS q1
```

and when i run the query against data I get plenty of results.

> However when i run a simply mysqli i get an error:
>   the error is: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object...

the rest is boilerplate

```
    $query_line_chart_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_linechart_sql);

     while($linechart_result_row = $query_line_chart_result->fetch_object()){
     //do something
    }
```

EDIT:
new errors appears the query is not working, despite it working in phpmyadmin

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT q1.d, q1.c, (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c) AS rt FROM (SELECT ' at line 1

Comment: probably failing to connect to the database. check your connection.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but you might need to use `mysqli_multi_query` for that statement as there are two statements

Comment: You should really stop using mysqli and move to PDO